# EEA Family Permit from USA-VFS Return Postage

Tags: visas, uk

The EEA FP application on the visas4uk site instruct after biometrics appointment that the application and supporting documents with original passport must be sent to NY (multiple addresses given) with an electronic UPS return postage from VFS Global but EEA Family Permit is NOT an option on their website drop down box. Any insights?

Comment: Are you sure it is a legitimate site?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa